# Where is desktop wallpape for Lubuntu 20.04.02?

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background

I switched to a solid colour wallpaper but now I want the original wallpaper which was a blue theme with a bird-like creatue on it.  I can't find where it's stored. I ran

```
     > gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

It retuned

```
       'file://usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/adwaita-timed.xml'
```

but usr/share/backgrounds/ is empty.

Where can I find the file? either on the web or on my machine would be OK.

Thanks

Comment: I found it: /usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/2004-lubuntu-wire-humming.png

Answer (score 2):

Wallpaper advice can be found in the Lubuntu manual

- https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.5/desktop.html?highlight=wallpaper
- https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html?highlight=wallpaper

The included wallpapers are found in `/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/`